# Gif анимация в Delphi

Tags: delphi, анимация

Хочу сделать анимацию загрузки в своей программе. Читал что компонент Image1 это умеет, но у меня не воспроизводит анимацию.

Как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

http://melander.dk/delphi/gifimage/

В новых версиях Delphi поддерживается из коробки, просто в TImage загружаем GIF картинку и включаем анимацию:

```
(Image1.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage).Animate := True;
```

Можно контролировать анимацию через AnimateLoop и AnimateSpeed.

Comment: А как сделать прозрачный фон для гифки? Что бы не было черного фона рядом с ней.

Comment: @atomik Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки "[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)". Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.